# Longest Common Substring from Trie

Tags: python, prefix, trie, suffix, longest-substring

i'm trying to obtain the longest common substring from two strings and have coded a  trie, but im not too sure how to obtain the longest common substring based on this trie. Could someone please help, thanks!

```
class TrieNode:
    def __init__(self):
        self.children = [None] * 27
        self.isLeaf = False
class Trie:
    def __init__(self):
        """
        Initialize your data structure here.
        """
        self.root = TrieNode()
    def insert(self, word: str) -> None:
        """
        Inserts a word into the trie.
        """
        current = self.root 
        for letter in word:
            index = ord(letter) - ord('a')
            if not current.children[index]:
                current.children[index] = TrieNode()
            current = current.children[index]
        current.isLeaf = True
    def search(self, word: str) -> bool:
        """
        Returns if the word is in the trie.
        """
        current = self.root 
        for letter in word:
            index = ord(letter) - ord('a')
            if not current.children[index]:
                return False 
            current = current.children[index]
        return current.isLeaf and current
    def startsWith(self, prefix: str) -> bool:
        """
        Returns if there is any word in the trie that starts with the given prefix.
        """
        current = self.root 
        for letter in prefix:
            index = ord(letter) - ord('a')
            if not current.children[index]:
                return False
            current = current.children[index]
        return True
```

Comment: What is the purpose of this trie? To store two strings?

Comment: to store a string. i was intending to concatenate the two strings using a character such as '$'

Comment: Trie will not be useful. Suffix tree could be.